# Code creates new .txt file in one .py but not in another .py

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a code which creates a new .txt file to which I will add data later on.

For testing and debugging I wrote it in another .py file and it's working. However when i copy the code to my main file it's not working anymore but it's not giving me an error either.

```
culturename_raw = str("filename123")

def create_rawfile():
    outfile = open(culturename_raw, "a")

    outfile.write("\n" + "text that I'm adding" + "\n")

    outfile.close()
    print("rawfile created")

create_rawfile()
```

When I run this code in my test .py it's creating a file with the name, writes the text und prints "rawfile created".

When I run this code in my main .py there is no error code and even prints "rawfile created" but there is no text file created.

I'm using Python 3.8 and PyCharm Community 2020.2 if that matters.

Comment: Is your `main.py` file in the same directory as your `test.py` file?

Comment: Yes it is. Both are also saved in the same PyCharm project.

Comment: if you have this code in your `main.py` program, and you _delete_ `filename123` before running it, does it get recreated?

Comment: To get it straight - you're simply running the same code from two different files?

Comment: Yes I'm running the exact same code from two different files.

Comment: If i delete the filename I get: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `culturename_raw = str("filename123")` to `culturename_raw = str("filename123.txt")`. You have to have the '.txt' extension.

Comment: Unfortunately makes no difference, the file is still not created. Sorry

Comment: If main.py and test.py are in the same directory, and you run that same function, then a new file won't be created, rather, the file that was initially created in test.py will just be appended in main.py. @Curcube Also, if you want a new file, then you'll have to change the name.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from but this was simply not the case, as it somehow wasnt appended to the other file. Changing the name also made no difference. However i solved the problem by creating a copy of the main.py and moving it to another folder. There its working as expected. Thank you for giving me the idea.

Comment: @Curcube Thank you! If you ever completely figure out why that is then please come back here and tell me. I use PyCharm as well.